# Session.IsNewSession in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, session

I am migrating an ASP.NET MVC application to ASP.NET Core 3.1.

And I have a code to check if the session was timed out in my controller, like this:

```
if (Session.IsNewSession) {
```

How can I check it in ASP.NET Core?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default implementation of `ISession` is `DistributedSession`. This does not expose any property for `IsNewSession` although its constructor accepts a parameter named `isNewSessionKey`. So you can use `reflection` to get that private field of `_isNewSessionKey` to check it. But that way is not very standard, the name may be changed in future without notifying you any design-time error.

You have several points to intercept and get the info here. The first point is to create a custom `ISessionStore` (default by `DistributedSessionStore`) to intercept the call to `ISessionStore.Create` which gives access to `isNewSessionKey`. You can capture that value into a request feature just like how the framework set the `ISessionFeature` after creating the session. Here's the code:

```
//create the feature interface & class
public interface ISessionExFeature {
    bool IsNewSession { get; }
}
public class SessionExFeature : ISessionExFeature {
    public SessionExFeature(bool isNewSession){
         IsNewSession = isNewSession;
    }
    public bool IsNewSession { get; }
}

//the custom ISessionStore
public class CustomDistributedSessionStore : DistributedSessionStore, ISessionStore
{        
    readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public CustomDistributedSessionStore(IDistributedCache cache, 
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,            
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) : base(cache, loggerFactory)
    {            
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    ISession ISessionStore.Create(string sessionKey, TimeSpan idleTimeout, TimeSpan ioTimeout, Func<bool> tryEstablishSession, bool isNewSessionKey)
    {
        var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        if(httpContext != null)
        {
            var sessionExFeature = new SessionExFeature(isNewSessionKey);             
            httpContext.Features.Set<ISessionExFeature>(sessionExFeature);
        }
        return Create(sessionKey, idleTimeout, ioTimeout, tryEstablishSession, isNewSessionKey);
    }
}

//register the custom ISessionStore inside Startup.ConfigureServices
services.Replace(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(ISessionStore), typeof(CustomDistributedSessionStore), ServiceLifetime.Transient));            

//an extension method to help get the ISessionExFeature conveniently
public static class SessionExFeatureHttpContextExtensions {
     public static bool HasNewSession(this HttpContext context){
         return context.Features.Get<ISessionExFeature>()?.IsNewSession ?? false;
     }
}
```

To use it in your code:

```
if (HttpContext.HasNewSession()) {
    //...
}
```

Another point to intercept and get the info is customize both the `ISessionStore` and `ISession`. Which means you create a sub class of `DistributedSession` and expose the property for `IsNewSession`. That may require more code but it looks more like the old way of getting the info (directly from the `Session` not kind of via an extension method on `HttpContext`).